# Best approach for automatically adding child nodes to a ExtJS TreePanel when an update happens matching some criteria?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am working with a TreePanel/TreeStore in ExtJS 4.1.1, with autoSync enabled and API calls to server endpoints defined via an Ajax proxy.

When a node is created with certain properties set, I have the server automatically add 2 child nodes during the autoSync call to the create API endpoint, and the server response text looks like this:

```
{
  "success" : true,
  "errorMsg" : null,
  "children" : {
    "id" : "toolbox-42",
    "parentId" : null,
    "itemName" : "My Toolbox",
    "nodeType" : "toolbox",
    "children" : [{
        "id" : "tool-91",
        "parentId" : "toolbox-42",
        "itemName" : "Default Tool 1",
        "nodeType" : "tool",
        "leaf" : true,
      }, {
        "id" : "tool-92",
        "parentId" : "toolbox-42",
        "itemName" : "Default Tool 2",
        "nodeType" : "tool",
        "leaf" : true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Setting the node's properties via the `"children"` key at the root level works just fine. The `"id"` property is set at the inserted node just fine.

My problem is that the child nodes that the server added don't appear in the tree. How do I get these added to the tree view?

Here are some solutions I have considered:

- In the server response, make the root level `"children"` object into an array, and append the new nodes to the end of the array (instead of nesting them under their parent node). The extractData method in Ext.data.reader.Reader (source [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Reader2.html#Ext-data-reader-Reader)) indicates all returned records will be extracted. *But,* the commitRecords method in Ext.data.Operation ([here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Operation.html#Ext-data-Operation)) only updates the number of clientRecords included in the request, which obviously does not include any new records coming down the pike in the server's response.
- After the server's response, manually add the records to the treestore client-side using the `"children"` node in the server's response. *But,* there seems to be no easy way to mark these records as "already synced".
- Don't add the records on the server at all; instead, manually add them on the client before the sync operation takes place (thus, the sync operation will give the server 3 inserts to do). *But,* the child nodes in the create request won't have a parentId set, because the server hasn't yet added the parent node and returned the id as a response.
- Attach an event handler that will fire once after the server has added the parent node, and then add the child nodes programmatically on the client (which would then be auto-synced to the server). *But,* this would requires 2 server round trips. Also, the only candidate event I know of is `'write'` in Ext.data.TreeStore, and there is no corresponding `'failwrite'` event which could be used to remove the listener in case the write operation fails. I could add an abstraction layer to provide that... but I would rather not if Sencha already built a better way.

Any other suggestions? I will accept a suggestion that works or any statement/link describing how Sencha recommends addressing this problem.

Thanks.

UPDATE: My store, proxy, and reader are configured as follows:

```
  var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model :    'App.models.Task',
    autoLoad : true,
    autoSync : true,
    proxy : {
      type : 'ajax',
      api : {
        create :  appUrl + 'Data/InsertTreeData',
        read :    appUrl + 'Data/GetTreeData',
        update :  appUrl + 'Data/UpdateTreeData',
        destroy : appUrl + 'Data/DeleteTreeData'
      },
      reader : {
        type : 'json',
        messageProperty : 'errorMsg'
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: can you share how your store and reader are configured?

Comment: @dbrin - See my update to the question.

Answer (score 2):

What I do when I add a node to the tree on the server side is grab the parent object id (it could be the root and that is fine) and then run the refreshParent routine that looks like this:

```
var node = this.store.getNodeById(id);
if (node){
        this.store.load({node:node});
}
```

Context here is the tree panel. This routine reloads specific branch of the tree.

Comment: May I ask how this code is started on the client? There is no `'aftersync'` event on the store, and the `'write'` event only is fired if the sync was successful.

Comment: I used an Ajax request to trigger creation of additional nodes on the server side. The callback then runs the routine.

Comment: My question is how to do this in the context of an auto-synced change.